# Loading fxml scene with many components takes too long

Tags: performance, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I am new to javafx and developing a desktop applicaiton using netbeans 7.4 and java version 7.

In my project there are 2 fxml files, first one with less number of UI components and the other with too many components. When I navigate from first fxml to second fxml it is taking too much time, whereas from second to first navigation is very fast and hardly took couple of seconds. I am trying to load new FXML file as below.

```
@FXML private TableView tableViewId;
Parent root = null;
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = null ;

Stage stage=(Stage) tableViewId.getScene().getWindow();

fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/performance.fxml"));
root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 930, 700);
stage.setScene(scene);

stage.show();
```

It works fine when i run this code using java version 7u51.
But when i use java version 7u21 it takes long time to open the page, approx 15 min.

Could you please tell me what is the error I am doing and help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks,

Sanjay

Comment: really? can you try with other system with same application?

Comment: Just use 7u51 if it works fine in that version.

Comment: @Jewelsea I need to use 7u21 as most of the system is having this version.

Comment: @JavaMan Yes i tried with other system too, but same result.